# Return NSDictionary from Async NSURLConnection/Class

Tags: json, asynchronous, nsdictionary

What I'm trying to do is create a class that returns a NSDictionary of Json Data when it's called. I have done the same thing in the past with images however I'm a bit confused on how to implement it with a NSDictionary.

What I want to do is load a view and then send the request in the background to get some Json data (async) and return the dictionary with the data to be used. I'm going to be loading a lot of Json data in a lot of different views so it should be a reusable class.

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [self init];

    if (self)
    {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        [self loadWithURL:url];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)loadWithURL:(NSURL *)url    
{
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSError *error = nil;

    jsonReturn = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

}
```

I thought about just adding the result to a protocol that the views can access however there must be a simpler/cleaner way right? Is there a way to have it RETURN the NSdictionary like so:

NSDictionary *dictionary = [LoadURLJSon initWithURL:myurl];

And it gets back the NSDictionary?

Comment: What you want is a sync operation on top of an async API (specifically, `[NSURLConnection start]`). You cannot do that without some heavy thread juggling, and it's a bad idea anyway - async is really the way to go. Don't throw the asynchronicity away.

Comment: I know you're right I had been debating it myself - So do you think I should go a protocol route and make all of the classes that need it conform to the protocol?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a sync operation on top of an async API (specifically, `[NSURLConnection start]`). You cannot do that without some heavy thread juggling, and it's a bad idea anyway - async is really the way to go. Don't throw the asynchronicity away.

The best way to do a one-shot async retrieval method is building a method that takes a URL, an `NSObject` and a selector as parameters, and once the request is done, calls the said selector on the said object, providing the NSDictionary as a parameter. That's the Objective C way of doing callbacks.

The method would internally instantiate your class, pass the callback info along, and initiate the request. Once the request is done and JSON is parsed into NSDictionary, you call `[performSelector:]` on the callback `NSObject`.

If you want a sync operation after all, use `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest]` rather than `[NSURLConnection start]`.

Comment: Thanks! See below for the complete implementation using a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with! it should be of use to those who pass here in the future.

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol LoadJsonDelegate <NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate>
@optional
- (void) downloadFinished;
- (void) downloadReceivedData;
- (void) dataDownloadFailed: (NSString *) reason;
@end

@interface LoadURLJson : NSObject
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    int expectedLength;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (strong) NSString *urlString;
@property (weak) id <LoadJsonDelegate> delegate;

-(void)start;
-(void)cancel;

+ (id)download:(NSString *)aURLString withDelegate:(id <LoadJsonDelegate>)aDelegate;

@end
```

The .m

```
#import "LoadURLJson.h"
#define SAFE_PERFORM_WITH_ARG(THE_OBJECT, THE_SELECTOR, THE_ARG) (([THE_OBJECT respondsToSelector:THE_SELECTOR]) ? [THE_OBJECT performSelector:THE_SELECTOR withObject:THE_ARG] : nil)

@implementation LoadURLJson

@synthesize receivedData, delegate, urlString;

+ (id) download:(NSString *)aURLString withDelegate:(id <LoadJsonDelegate>)aDelegate
{
    if (!aURLString)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error. No URL string");
        return nil;
    }

    LoadURLJson *loadJson = [[self alloc] init];
    loadJson.urlString = aURLString;
    loadJson.delegate = aDelegate;
    [loadJson start];

    return loadJson;
}

-(void)start   
{
    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];

    // Check for bad connection
    expectedLength = [response expectedContentLength];
    if (expectedLength == NSURLResponseUnknownLength)
    {
        NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invalid URL [%@]", urlString];
        SAFE_PERFORM_WITH_ARG(delegate, @selector(dataDownloadFailed:), reason);
        [connection cancel];
        [self cleanup];
        return;
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    SAFE_PERFORM_WITH_ARG(delegate, @selector(downloadReceivedData), nil);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    SAFE_PERFORM_WITH_ARG(delegate, @selector(downloadFinished), nil);
}

-(void)cleanup
{
    self.urlString = nil;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [self cleanup];
}

-(void)cancel
{
    [self cleanup];
}

@end
```

Useage - in yourView.h

```
#import "LoadURLJson.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <LoadJsonDelegate>
{
    LoadURLJson *loadJson;
}
```

youView.m

Call With:

```
loadJson = [LoadURLJson download:@"url" withDelegate:self];
```

Then Implement

```
-(void)downloadFinished
{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:loadJson.receivedData];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
}
```

Based off DownloadHelper Here: https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook

BSD Licence.